# Modern Computability Theory Books

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I’m looking for a book on computability theory that is relatively modern. Most books I see that are referenced, like Soare’s book, were written a while back. I would imagine that computability theory is a field that changes quickly (but of course have no idea). Are books like Soare’s still relevant? If the field and it’s really have changed, what are some more modern/recent books on the topic that are recommended?

Comment: Some title: [Computability Theory](https://www.google.it/search?q=computability+theory&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjuoHu_KDaAhXMWSwKHaIiDoYQ_AUIECgB&biw=1366&bih=662).

Comment: Soare's old book is absolutely still relevant: while the frontier of the field has of course evolved, Soare's treatment of the fundamentals is in no way obsolete. In fact, while there are certainly a number of criticisms (e.g. the notation is old, the hints for the exercises often give the entire answer, the exposition is terse), on the whole I think it is my favorite. He has a [new book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642319327) with more friendly exposition, but which covers much less material and is more verbose.

Comment: My main complaint about Soare's old book is with regard to the notation. The modern notation for the $e$th Turing machine on input $n$ is "$\Phi_e(n)$;" the old notation, which Soare uses in his old book, is "$\{e\}(n)$." Personally I find this harder to read, and at times confusing.

Comment: What is computability theory ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus AKA recursion theory; see the first sentence of [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory). My understanding is that in the 90s, Soare strongly advocated for the name "computability theory" instead, and this has become common (though not exclusive; I'd say it's about a 50/50 split); see [this part of the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory#Name_of_the_subject).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, I guess I went on a rant there. Oh well, you can only do well to heed my words. It is serious, changing language may seem to be an innocuous thing but it has big consequences, which is why politicians (the aspiration of all professors), ideologues and  activists do it. And yeah, I feel that they value other things above their own scholarship.